# Only one (the first) radio button in a group is selectable / active

Tags: php, html, radio-button

I have a few groups of radio buttons being generated using data from a database. Currently I am only able to click on / successfully select the first of these groups of radio buttons, the others are unresponsive.

The code when I test it separately in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7XUyD/) works fine, so I don't think it is that, however here it is anyway

**HTML generated/source:**

```
<div class="radio">
  <div>
      <input type="radio" id="a" value="A" name="Q1" /> 
      <span class="inline">A</span>
  </div>
  <div>
      <input type="radio" id="b" value="B" name="Q1" /> 
      <span class="inline">B</span>
  </div>
  <div>
      <input type="radio" id="c" value="C" name="Q1" /> 
      <span class="inline">C</span>
  </div>
  <div>
      <input type="radio" id="d" value="D" name="Q1" /> 
      <span class="inline">D</span>
  </div>
  <div>
      <input type="radio" id="e" value="E" name="Q1" /> 
      <span class="inline">E</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

For what it is worth here is the PHP I am using to build the above:

```
$questions .='
<div class="radio">
';

foreach($values_data as $ke=>$va)
    {
    $questions.='
    <div><input  '.$tooltip.' type="radio" id="question_'.$i.'_'.$va['value'].'" value="'.$va['value'].'" name="question_'.$i.'" />
    <span class="inline">'.$va['value'].'</span></div>
    ';
    }

$questions .='
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
';

echo $questions;
```

Where the above sits inside a loop that is defining $i and calling on databases to build arrays etc.

There are no errors in my console. Any ideas what this could be? Thanks

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/b8jFF/1/) is the portion of the actual source code generated. Also working in jsfiddle.

Comment: var_dump() $values_data and look if the values of variables fit your expectations.

Comment: *"the others are unresponsive."* which "others"?

Comment: Can you post the 'generated' HTML ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well there are 5 radio buttons, I can only click on the first one, the other four are unresponsive

Comment: @Foobar have added an edit for the actual code. It works in jsfiddle though :/

Comment: There could be a transparent element (e.g. a `<div>`) overlapping your radio buttons. Open your browser's dev tools to check.

Comment: Worked fine for me on my server. How are you using your final produced code? Plus, does your final working copy include the `<form></form>` tags? @Gideon

Comment: Tested [PHP TEST](http://3v4l.org/YaOaW)

Comment: Also check what your CSS class (if there is one already set) to see what it's doing to probably manipulate it. Load your final working copy into your browser and check the source. @Gideon

Comment: I also noticed in your other questions that you're using jQuery for some. Make sure that it's loaded or is not interferring with anything. @Gideon

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for all the ideas - the css one seems like it might be a winner: the class "radio" has "float right" as a property - when I disable this it allows me to check all the buttons. Any idea what's casuing that? When I look at the div in tilt/firefox everything seems to be in order (nothing covered up, overlapping etc).

Comment: You're welcome. I have no idea as to why it would react that way. I added `.radio { float:right; }` and it worked. I did this inside FF 25 and IE7 and both worked well. Do you have anything else that's CSS-related that would possibly overlap it? It could be something really silly. Which browser/version are you using and DOCTYPE?

Comment: Plus try adding a `<label>` tag to see if that will help it. @Gideon

Comment: @Fred-ii- testing in FF25 and chrome29, DOCTYPE HTML 4.01, I've got  basic css on that div, dev tools confirm that it's only having margin, font, display inline and float right applied to it.

Added label instead of span, no help there, also threw in z-index: 99 in case that helped but no.

Interestingly removing then reapplying the float right or display inline style to the class "radio" wakes them up and they all work... hmm, something odd here!

Comment: @Fred-ii- well, for now forcing display: block to the radio element seems to have solved it, but it feels like a bit of a hack! Thanks for your efforts :)

Comment: You're welcome. Might have just been a cache thing. It's happened to me before. Firefox can be screwy that way. @Gideon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of closing this question:

This was a strange issue where by it seemed like the css properties were preventing proper element interaction: removing either float: right, or display: inline from the radio elements made them click able again.

I am not sure why this is, but I solved the issue by forcing the .radio class to have display: block; instead.