# Radio buttons generated in a PHP for loop will only let me click the first one

Tags: php, html, radio-button

I'm bulding a booking system in PHP and need to ouput a range of times available to book in a calendar format. A user can select only one time in the form, so I need them to be radio buttons. I've got it to output the available times fine, but I can't select any thing other than the first radio button in any of the days.

I thought this might help - [Only one (the first) radio button in a group is selectable / active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19934087/only-one-the-first-radio-button-in-a-group-is-selectable-active) as the idea is the same but the solution is a CSS problem which I don't have.

$timeArray below is an array of the available times stored e.g 2014-05-05-01, 2014-05-05-02, 2014-05-06-01. The last two digits in each element refer to a time period for that day.

```
<?php 
for($i=0;$i<count($timeArray); $i++){ ?>
 <input type="radio" name="request" id="request<?php echo $timeArray[$i]; ?>" value="<?php echo $timeArray[$i];?>" /> 
<?php } ?>
```

It outputs the series of times and radio buttons fine, but I can only select the first radio button in each day of the calendar.

As there is only supposed to be one value coming from the whole form, I left the name just as 'request'. Is this right? I've tried it as

```
request[]
```

and

```
request[$i]
```

which made no difference, and also tried it as

```
request[<?php echo $timeArray[$i]; ?>]
```

which made all the buttons selectable as they all had different names then.

Can you point me in the right direction please?

This is the calendar code:

```
<table width="100%" align="center">
                        <tr valign="baseline">
                          <td valign="top" nowrap="nowrap" align="center"><?php 
    //set variables to today
        $day = date('d');
        $month = date('m');
        $year = date('Y');

        $monthCount = 0;

    for($monthCount = 0; $monthCount <3; $monthCount++){
    if ($month <= (date('m')+1)){
    //first day of the month
    $first_day = mktime(0,0,0,$month, 1, $year) ;

    //month name
    $title = date('F', $first_day) ;
    $day_of_week = date('D', $first_day) ;

    //determine how many blank days needed before the first day of the month
    switch($day_of_week){
    case "Sun": $blank = 0; break;
    case "Mon": $blank = 1; break;
    case "Tue": $blank = 2; break;
    case "Wed": $blank = 3; break;
    case "Thu": $blank = 4; break;
    case "Fri": $blank = 5; break;
    case "Sat": $blank = 6; break;
    }

    //how many days in the current month
    $days_in_month = cal_days_in_month(0, $month, $year) ; 

                            <table border="1" class='scalendar'>
                              <tr>
                                <th colspan = "7"> <?php echo $title;?>&nbsp;<?php echo $year; ?></th>
                              </tr>
                              <tr class='scalendar'>
                                <td>Sun</td>
                                <td>Mon</td>
                                <td>Tue</td>
                                <td>Wed</td>
                                <td>Thu</td>
                                <td>Fri</td>
                                <td>Sat</td>
                              </tr>
                              <?php
    $day_count = 1;
    ?>
                              <tr >
                                <?php
            while ( $blank > 0 )
            { ?>
                                <td></td>
                                <?php
            $blank = $blank-1;
            $day_count++;
            } 
            $day_num = 1;
            while ( $day_num <= $days_in_month )
            {
            ?>
                                <td valign="top"><label> <span class="main"><?php echo $day_num; ?></span><br />
                                    <?php 
            //code displays months < 10 as single digit numbers - correct this with the following
            if(strlen($month) == 1){
                $month = "0".$month;
                }
            //code displays days < 10 as single digit numbers - correct this with the following
            if(strlen($day_num) == 1){
                $day_num = "0".$day_num;
                }
if(count($timeArray) > 0){
    for($i=0;$i<count($timeArray); $i++){
<input type="radio" name="request" id="request<?php echo $timeArray[$i]; ?>" value="<?php echo $timeArray[$i];?>" />  
 echo "<br>";   
} //end of for loop
} // end of if array length is > 0 loop
 if(count($timeArray) == 0){ 
           //today has no availability ?>
                                    -
                                    <?php }  ?>
                                  </label></td>
                                <?php $day_num++;
            $day_count++;

            //new row every week
            if ($day_count > 7)
            {
            ?>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <?php 
    $day_count = 1;
    }
    } 
    while ( $day_count >1 && $day_count <=7 )
    {
    ?>
                                <td></td>
                                <?php
    $day_count++;
    }//end of while day count is > 1 and <=7
    $month = $month+1;
    if($month > 12){
    $year = $year+1;
    $month = 1;
    }
    echo "<br />";
    }}//end of while month is less than current month +2
    ?>
                              </tr>
                              <tr></tr>
                            </table>
```

This is the HTML code generated for the form:

```
<form action="request.php?" method="post" name="form2" id="form2">
                  <tr>
                    <td class="main"><table width="100%" align="center">
                        <tr valign="baseline">
                          <td valign="top" nowrap="nowrap" align="center">                                <table border="1" class='scalendar'>
                              <tr>
                                <th colspan = "7"> May&nbsp;2014</th>
                              </tr>
                              <tr class='scalendar'>
                                <td>Sun</td>
                                <td>Mon</td>
                                <td>Tue</td>
                                <td>Wed</td>
                                <td>Thu</td>
                                <td>Fri</td>
                                <td>Sat</td>
                              </tr>
                                                                <tr >
                                                                    <td></td>
                                                                    <td></td>
                                                                    <td></td>
                                                                    <td></td>
                                                                    <td valign="top"><label> <span class="main">1</span><br />
                                    09:15 - 09:30                            <input type="radio" name="request" id="request2014-05-01-2" value="2014-05-01-2" />  
                         <br>09:30 - 09:45                           <input type="radio" name="request" id="request2014-05-01-3" value="2014-05-01-3" />  
                         <br>10:00 - 10:15                           <input type="radio" name="request" id="request2014-05-01-5" value="2014-05-01-5" />  
                         <br>10:15 - 10:30                           <input type="radio" name="request" id="request2014-05-01-6" value="2014-05-01-6" />  
                         <br>11:45 - 12:00                           <input type="radio" name="request" id="request2014-05-01-12" value="2014-05-01-12" />  
                         <br>                                                                              </label></td>
                                                                    <td valign="top"><label> <span class="main">2</span><br />
                                    09:00 - 09:15                            <input type="radio" name="request" id="request2014-05-02-1" value="2014-05-02-1" />  
                         <br>10:00 - 10:15                           <input type="radio" name="request" id="request2014-05-02-5" value="2014-05-02-5" />  
                         <br>10:30 - 10:45                           <input type="radio" name="request" id="request2014-05-02-7" value="2014-05-02-7" />  
                         <br>11:00 - 11:15                           <input type="radio" name="request" id="request2014-05-02-9" value="2014-05-02-9" />  
                         <br>11:15 - 11:30                           <input type="radio" name="request" id="request2014-05-02-10" value="2014-05-02-10" />  
                         <br>11:30 - 11:45                           <input type="radio" name="request" id="request2014-05-02-11" value="2014-05-02-11" />  
                         <br>                                                                              </label></td>
                                                                    <td valign="top"><label> <span class="main">3</span><br />
                                                                            -
                                                                          </label></td>
                                                                  </tr>
                              <tr>
                                                                    <td valign="top"><label> <span class="main">4</span><br />
                                                                            -
                                                                          </label></td>
                                                                    <td valign="top"><label> <span class="main">5</span><br />
                                                                            -
                                                                          </label></td>
                                                                    <td valign="top"><label> <span class="main">6</span><br />
                                                                            -
                                                                          </label></td>
                                                                    <td valign="top"><label> <span class="main">7</span><br />
                                                                            -
                                                                          </label></td>
                                                                    <td valign="top"><label> <span class="main">8</span><br />
                                                                            -
                                                                          </label></td>
                                                                    <td valign="top"><label> <span class="main">9</span><br />
                                                                            -
                                                                          </label></td>
                                                                    <td valign="top"><label> <span class="main">10</span><br />
                                                                            -
                                                                          </label></td>
                                                                  </tr>
                              <tr>
                                                                    <td valign="top"><label> <span class="main">11</span><br />
                                                                            -
                                                                          </label></td>
                                                                    <td valign="top"><label> <span class="main">12</span><br />
                                                                            -
                                                                          </label></td>
                                                                    <td valign="top"><label> <span class="main">13</span><br />
                                                                            -
                                                                          </label></td>
                                                                    <td valign="top"><label> <span class="main">14</span><br />
                                                                            -
                                                                          </label></td>
                                                                    <td valign="top"><label> <span class="main">15</span><br />
                                                                            -
                                                                          </label></td>
                                                                    <td valign="top"><label> <span class="main">16</span><br />
                                                                            -
                                                                          </label></td>
                                                                    <td valign="top"><label> <span class="main">17</span><br />
                                                                            -
                                                                          </label></td>
                                                                  </tr>
                              <tr>
                                                                    <td valign="top"><label> <span class="main">18</span><br />
                                                                            -
                                                                          </label></td>
                                                                    <td valign="top"><label> <span class="main">19</span><br />
                                                                            -
                                                                          </label></td>
                                                                    <td valign="top"><label> <span class="main">20</span><br />
                                                                            -
                                                                          </label></td>
                                                                    <td valign="top"><label> <span class="main">21</span><br />
                                                                            -
                                                                          </label></td>
                                                                    <td valign="top"><label> <span class="main">22</span><br />
                                                                            -
                                                                          </label></td>
                                                                    <td valign="top"><label> <span class="main">23</span><br />
                                                                            -
                                                                          </label></td>
                                                                    <td valign="top"><label> <span class="main">24</span><br />
                                                                            -
                                                                          </label></td>
                                                                  </tr>
                              <tr>
                                                                    <td valign="top"><label> <span class="main">25</span><br />
                                                                            -
                                                                          </label></td>
                                                                    <td valign="top"><label> <span class="main">26</span><br />
                                                                            -
                                                                          </label></td>
                                                                    <td valign="top"><label> <span class="main">27</span><br />
                                                                            -
                                                                          </label></td>
                                                                    <td valign="top"><label> <span class="main">28</span><br />
                                                                            -
                                                                          </label></td>
                                                                    <td valign="top"><label> <span class="main">29</span><br />
                                                                            -
                                                                          </label></td>
                                                                    <td valign="top"><label> <span class="main">30</span><br />
                                                                            -
                                                                          </label></td>
                                                                    <td valign="top"><label> <span class="main">31</span><br />
                                                                            -
                                                                          </label></td>
                                                                  </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <br />                                  </tr>
                              <tr></tr>
                            </table></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr valign="baseline">
                          <td valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr valign="baseline">
                          <td valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center">
                              <input name="btnSubmit" type="submit" class="main" id="btnSubmit" value="Request" /> 
                              <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form2" />
                            </div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr valign="baseline">
                          <td valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table></td>
                  </tr>
                </form>
```

Comment: Can you show us the generated HTML?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, sorry to sound stupid. The only bit of HTML for the radio buttons that's used is what I've written above. Did you mean for the calendar? I've used the calendar code many times before and this bit with the radio buttons is the only thing that's different, which is why I thought it was this.

Comment: Yes - it would be easier for us to diagnose the problem if we could see the relevant markup that is produced which causes the problem.

Comment: Ok, I've done that above

Comment: Actually, you haven't. You posted more of your PHP code - which is fine. When you load the page into your browser can you view the source and post the HTML that was rendered here?

Comment: Ditto to what Jay asked.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood there. I've done that now, I've only added availability for 2 days.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a quote around one of your attruibutes:

```
 <input type="radio" name="request" id="request<?php echo $timeArray[$i]; ?> value="<?php echo $timeArray[$i];?>
                                                                        ^^^^^^
                                                                          HERE
```

Comment: Missed that - thank you. I've amended my code and in the explanation above, but I'm still only able to click the first radio button.